# replace dataframe header before printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv that looks like:

```
bookId,bookName,author,year,genre,bookCount
1,book1,au1,1989,gen1,89
2,book2,au2,788,gen2,55
3,book3,au3,9799,gen1,7
```

When i read it and print it to terminal using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('some3.csv',index_col=0)
print(df)
```

I get:

```
       bookName author  year genre  bookCount
bookId
1         book1    au1  1989  gen1         89
2         book2    au2   788  gen2         55
3         book3    au3  9799  gen1          7
```

(Notice that bookId comes in a different line, if someone could explain that as well, it'd be helpful since I am a beginner)

However, I want to display the df as: *(custom header)*

```
Book ID  Book Name  Author  Published Year   Genre  Book Count
1        book1      au1     1989             gen1   89
2        book2      au2     788              gen2   55
3        book3      au3     9799             gen1   7
```

And sometimes like: *(without genre column)*

```
Book ID  Book Name  Author  Published Year  Book Count
1        book1      au1     1989            89
2        book2      au2     788             55
3        book3      au3     9799            7
```

(By replacing header with a custom one, and sometimes omit a few columns if required)

Also, at last I'd like to write this df to a new csv file that hopefully looks like this:

```
Book ID,Book Name,Author,Published Year,Genre,Book Count
1,book1,au1,1989,gen1,89
2,book2,au2,788,gen2,55
3,book3,au3,9799,gen1,7
```

I'm open to adding a few parameters to pd.read_csv() to replace the header. (or change this statement entirely if necessary).

I'm also fine with creating a new df to copy values and add a custom header, or any other code adjustments.

But I cannot change the first(existing) csv file.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('some3.csv') 
# when you flag index col, it will read the first column as index , 
# that is why it is lower than other header
```

Then replace the column with `rename`

```
df = df.rename(columns={'bookId' : 'Book ID',  ....})
```

Then write to csv

```
df.to_csv('newfile.csv')
```

Comment: Sometimes OP wants to remove genre column. You could use `df.drop(columns=['genre'], inplace=True)`, or just select the columns you *do* want `df = df[['col1', 'col2']]`

Answer (score 0):

To change col name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'aa':[1,3], 'bb': [13,20]})
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
df
```

To drop col:

```
del df['column_name']
```

To print to CSV:

```
df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False)
```